# re-install or refresh files on windows subsystem for linux

Tags: windows-10

I accidentally deleted all of the directories in /usr/lib on windows subsystem for linux on Windows 10 when I meant to delete just one of the sub-folders (node_modules).  Because the shell always runs in sudo mode, there was no access denied restriction.  Now I am having major issues and want to re-install the base platform packages and start fresh, but have not been able to find any resources on doing so.

I mainly do javascript development, and nothing with npm will work (after I uninstalled and re-installed node multiple times)

**Example:**

```
root@WIN-05ANKLGA0J3:~# npm install -g gulp
fs.js:634
return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
               ^

Error: Unknown system error -25: Unknown system error -25, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:634:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:502:33)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:549:20)
    at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at startup (node.js:159:18)
    at node.js:444:3
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: this question belongs to superuser.com and was already answered there: http://superuser.com/a/1065579

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon my answer here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/reference

From powershell type `lxrun /uninstall /full` to remove the instance and all user data.  After that `lxrun /install` will re-download WSL from the windows store.

I found the answer by subscribing to the github issues page https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows and there was a reference to this page on one of the posts.